# ActionMailer doesn't use default from, or any "from" for that matter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mailer

I'm trying to send out "Welcome Emails" to my users, however, the default :from is not working. It is using the user_name I specify in the config/application.rb file.

This is the code I currently have.

config/application.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => "587",
  :domain               => "domain.com",
  :user_name            => "myemail@gmail.com",
  :password             => "password",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => 'email_i_want_to_send_from@gmail.com'

  def welcome_email
    mail(:to => "myemail@gmail.com", :subject => "welcome")
  end
end
```

Instead of receiving an email from **email_i_want_to_send_from@gmail.com**, a user would receive an email from **myemail@gmail.com**. (Yes, I am using actual email addresses and passwords when testing).

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any other smtp server you can try?  Everything looks correct,  it could be gmail being anal about disallowing the substitution of the from address.  GMail's weird,  I've had to hack around gmail once or twice.

Comment: Unfortunately... no :( All my accounts are gmail accounts. I guess I could make a Windows Live account or something to test it out.

Comment: Actually, I'll try using the servers smtp settings. I think its hosted on GoDaddy.

Comment: +1 to RadBrad.. You should use some STMP server in order to send and customize emails. Try: sendgrid.org

Comment: Did you try this: `mail(:to => "myemail@gmail.com", :subject => "welcome", :from => 'email_i_want_to_send_from@gmail.com')` ?

Comment: @Surya yes I did. It still doesn't work. I'm looking into sendgrid now.

Comment: Google won't allow you to do that I guess. Because, you are using a gmail account to send emails and I guess they won't let you play around with their system. sendgrid is quite easy to use. I hope that helps..

Comment: Google will not allow this because sending an email with a user account and changing (spoofing) the from email address is a hallmark of spammers and not needed for normal users.  You can also easily run your own SMTP on your server but be aware that many ISPs will blackhole email from EC2 or Cable subscriber IPs.  Your code is fine and should work on a non restricted SMTP server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google doesn't allow you to "spoof" a from address. I used Send Grid to send out my emails.