# Default from details rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

After searching I haven't found an answer, I need some details about the default from option of the action mailer in rails.

I'm using the action mailer with the google smtp server and no matter what I do the default from option is not working. Is this option an alias and can it be any mail address that doesn't exist, or does the mail address needs to exist ?
And can this option work if using google smtp server ?

For now I'm setting it like this in my development.rb file:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'default@development-server.com'
```

Comment: Did you tried: `config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'default@development-server.com'}` as explained here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration?

Comment: It seems to be an alias of "default", it shouldn't change anything :/ And I can't answer your other questions, sorry.

Comment: I tried setting it with your line but no luck, the email address is still unchanged :/

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer, as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10486733/6574669

When using google smtp server you can't use default from option to change your email address.